# Find capacity of water tank with a hole

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Suppose I have a water tank with unknown capacity. The water drains proportionality to how full it is, and when it is full it drains at 1 gallon/min.
>
> If the tank is half empty in 15 minutes, how much does the tank hold?

I'm not sure how to set this problem up. Do I model it as a diff. eq. That is, if $C$ is the capacity, then

$$\frac{dC}{dt} = C.$$

Solving this gives:

$$\int \frac{1}{C}dC = \int dt \quad\Rightarrow\quad C(t) = e^{t + k},$$

where $k$ is a constant. But I don't think this is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be the full capacity, and let $f(t)$ be how much the tank is filled at time $t$ minutes. We have:

$$f'(t) = -\frac{f(t)}{C}$$

$$f(0) = C$$

$$f(15) = \frac{C}{2}$$

Make sure you see why this models the situation. (For instance, why the minus sign? Or the division by $C$?) The first equation has general solution:

$$f(t) = ae^{-\frac{t - b}{C}}$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are any real numbers. Then, from the boundary conditions we must have:

$$(1)\ ae^{\frac{b}{C}} = C$$

$$(2)\ ae^{\frac{b}{C}-\frac{15}{C}}=\frac{C}{2}$$

Dividing $(1)$ by $(2)$, we get $e^{\frac{15}{C}} = 2$. Thus, $\frac{15}{C} = \ln(2)$, so $C = \boxed{\frac{15}{\ln(2)}\approx 21.640\text{ gal.}}$